# In ubuntu bash script when I try to convert wrong hexadecimal value is not throwing any error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

In Ubuntu when I try to convert Hexadecimal (ZZZZZ) its printing like 3777777.

It should display an error since hexadecimal if from A to F right?

```
DESKTOP-DQWCSON:~$ echo 'ibase=16; obase=8; ZZZZZ' |bc
3777777
```

Comment: I removed irrelevant _ubuntu_  and _linux_ tags from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not an error. From the *bc*  man page:

> Single digit numbers always have the value of the digit regardless of the value of ibase. (i.e. A = 10.)  For multi-digit numbers, bc  changes  all  input  digits  greater or equal to ibase to the value of ibase-1.

One may regard this as a design flow in `bc`, but it behaves as documented.